# EMV: No probability, but Chance of Success is given

Tags: probability, expected-value

In Expected Monetary Value (EMV), usually, the decision maker just multiply payoff/profit with the probability. Example, the decision maker is to decide where to invest his/her money. The number that corresponds to an alternative are the profit or payoff if the decision maker chooses to invest on it (e.g., investing in Bonds, in a Growing economy, the decision maker will get a profit of 45, but in a declining economy, he/she will gain a profit of 5):

| Alternatives | Growing | Declining |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bonds | 40 | 5 |
| Stocks | 70 | -13 |
| Mutual Funds | 53 | -5 |
| Probability | 0.6 | 0.4 |

To get the EMV of Bonds:

```
= (40 * 0.6)+(5 * 0.4)
= 24 + 2
= 26
```

So the EMV for Bonds is 26. Then 36.8 for Stocks and 29.8 for Mutual Funds. The highest EMV of the three is Stocks with 36.8. It means that the decision maker should invest in Stocks.

Here in this case, the probability is not given and instead gave Chance of Success for each alternative. The decision maker figures or sets the chance of success here:

| Alternatives | Growing | Declining | Chance of Success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bonds | 40 | 5 | 50% |
| Stocks | 70 | -13 | 60% |
| Mutual Funds | 53 | -5 | 75% |

**My take**: To get the EMV, what I did is I assumed the **Chance of Failure/Not Success**. For example, the chance of success of Bonds is 50%, so the chance of failure is 50%. For Stocks, the chance of success is 60%, so the chance of failure is 40%, and so on.

After that, I multiply the payoff/profit of Growing economy with the chance of success and add it with the product result of chance of failure and declining economy:

```
= (40 * 0.5)+(5 * 0.5)
= 20 + 2.5
= 22.5
```

The EMV of Bonds is 22.5.

```
= (70 * 0.6) + (-13 * 0.4)
= 42 + (-5.2)
= 36.8
```

The EMV of Stocks is 36.8.

```
= (53 * 0.75) + (-5 * 0.25)
= 39.75 + (-1.25)
= 38.5
```

The EMV of Mutual Funds is 38.5. The highest of the three is Mutual Funds with expected value of 38.5, meaning the decision maker should invest in Mutual Funds.

Am I correct with this approach in the second method, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  In the first table, what do the numbers $40$ and $5$ mean?  In your first computation, you appear to get $26$ for the EMV of Bonds (though I can't follow your computation), but then you write "so the EMV for Bonds is $32$".  What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry. I updated my post. It should be 26. 40 and 5 in Bonds row are payoffs or profit that you would gain if you invest in Bonds.

Comment: Are we to use the same Win/Lose probabilities for every asset class?  That seems odd.  And are you really assuming that Bonds can only go up?  That's not true, of course.

Comment: In any case, of course one might guess that "Chance of Success" was the same as "Probability of Winning" (seems likely enough, after all) but we can't read the author's mind and perhaps they meant something else.  If the author has indicated that only two outcomes are possible and has provided the probability of one of the two outcomes, then you can get the other probability as the two must add to $1$.

Comment: This is only an example and usually, in problem set, the tabular data is already given. And the task is to get the best alternative solution. You may watch a quick introduction to EMV and EVPI [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbv9E9D2BRQ).

Comment: We can only help you if you clearly define "chance of success".

Comment: @bluemaster the chance of success is figured or set by the decision maker.

Comment: Is his personal assessment of the probability based on beliefs? without knowing the given probability?

Comment: Ok. I think I´ve got it now. You are right. You're considering the personal assessment of the probabilitity of each event because it is what is available. And the decision maker is using the expected value to select the best alternative. I'm not, however, comfortable with the terminology "chance of success".